Navigating to LoginPage/MainPage on app start
I have a pretty standard application where a user needs to either be shown a LoginPage if the user is not authenticated or a MainPage if authenticated. The MainPage is a Shell Application with a Flyout menu.
I am trying to find the 'official' way to distinguish this navigation within the app. Currently, in my AppShell.xaml.cs I am performing this work OnAppearing. This consists of using a service provider to check authentication status (DI doesn't work here, so I have to explicitly reference the Service Provider).
public AppShell()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

protected override async void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();

    //need to do Authentication
    var auth = new FirebaseAuthorization();
    var authenticated = auth.IsAuthenticated();

    //if user is Authenticated, navigate to MainPage
    if(authenticated)
        await Current.GoToAsync($"//{nameof(MainPage)}");
}

In my AppShell, I have defined my Routes as follows.
  <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate login:LoginPage}" 
                FlyoutItemIsVisible="False" 
                Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled"
                Route="LoginPage"/>

  <FlyoutItem Title="Main">
    <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate mainPage:MainPage}" Route="MainPage" />
  </FlyoutItem>
  <FlyoutItem Title="Students">
    <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate student:StudentsPage}" Route="StudentsPage" />
  </FlyoutItem>
  <FlyoutItem Title="Teachers">
      <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate teachers:TeachersPage}" Route="TeachersPage"/>
  </FlyoutItem>

Observations:
In my AppShell, I still have to define the LoginPage even though I don't want it to appear in my Flyout, so the only way to disable it is to explicitly disable using the behavior flags. If I completely remove the LoginPage from AppShell, then I couldn't route to the LoginPage when the user signed out of the application.
I initially defined the Routes in the mauiprogram file as follows (instead of specifying Route="Login" in the AppShell:
Routing.RegisterRoute("Login", typeof(LoginPage));
I found that the TitleBar would show the back button instead of the flyout menu even though I was using Absolute Navigation to navigate to the MainPage:
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//{nameof(MainPage)}");
Overarching question, is my method of navigating based on authentication status done at the most optimal place (AppShell.xaml.cs)?
EDIT (clarifying question): On app startup, (1) I want to show either a Login Page or Main Page based on user authentication status. How? (2) I want to know if I need the Login page in my AppShell, (3) knowing that I need to Route to the Login page on signout.

You can set the LoginPage as default page in the App.cs: MainPage = new LoginPage();. And then navigation by: App.Current.MainPage = new AppShell();.

I found two articles referring to AppShell in Xamarin.Forms and how to handle checking for authenticated users. The Xamarin articles are identical to a Maui solution.
(1) https://youtu.be/ylbgWHB_gMI?si=Ywdj4BdQQjDNW47g
James navigates to a login page and checks authentication using the OnAppearing method. He also mentions that this can be done either on the Login page or in AppShell (which is where I perform my check in the code posted in the question).
(2) https://mallibone.com/post/xamarin-forms-shell-login
Mark uses an intermediary loading page between when the app starts and painting either the login page or main page. This seems a little overkill, but posting here in case anyone has an opinion.
I will continue with option (1).

My suggestion would be to create a custom navigation service, it should resolve your issue. it should be something along those lines. that way you can reg your routes in shell and bind and part of them to your Flyout
    public class NavigationService : INavigationService
    {
        public Task InitializeAsync() =>
            NavigateToAsync("//Overview");
    
        public Task NavigateToAsync(string route,bool loggedIn, IDictionary<string, object> routeParameters = null)
        {
            var shellNavigation = new ShellNavigationState(route);
    if(loggedIn)
            return routeParameters != null
                ? Shell.Current.GoToAsync(shellNavigation, routeParameters)
                : Shell.Current.GoToAsync(shellNavigation);
else
return Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//LoginPage");
        }
    
        public Task PopAsync() =>
            Shell.Current.GoToAsync("..");
    }


I am not following the usage here. On app startup, (1) I want to show either a Login Page or Main Page based on user authentication status. How? (2) I want to know if I need the Login page in my AppShell, (3) knowing that I need to Route to the Login page on signout.
